# Injecting service into another service in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have two services
`CarService` and `HomeService`.  I would like to inject `CarService` into `HomeService`, however it is always null. When it comes to injecting `CarService` into controllers it is working. Why am I doing wrong?

```
HomeService.$inject = ['carService']
function HomeService(carService){
    // here carService is null
}
```

**Edit**

```
CarService.$inject = ['$localStorage'];
function CarService($localStorage) {


var myCarsPromise = getCars();

  var myLocalStorage = $localStorage.$default({
        cars: null 
    });

   function getCars(){
      return ['car'];
   }

   return {
        getCars
    };

}
export default CarService
```

Answer (score 0):

Services are registered to modules via the Module API. Typically you use the Module factory API to register a service

```
//Car Service
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.factory('CarService', function() {
  //function body
});
```

To inject `Carservice` in your `Homeservice`, this is the approach

```
//Homeservice
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
 myModule.factory('Homeservice',['Carservice', function(Carservice) {}]))
```

Comment: I didn't tried yet. You should know, that injectiring CarService to controllers does work